# How to transpose an Excel spreadsheet using Excel Javascript on Mac

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

So in my Excel spreadsheet, there is column A which are events and column B which are categories. A1 and B1 are both headers and can be excluded from the transformation. I am trying to write a script that takes all the unique categories from column B and transposes it horizontally. These will become the new headers and then column A data will be populated underneath these new headers if the categories match in column B. I am having such a hard time getting this to work and would appreciate any help.

If I do it manually, I use the following two Excel formulas:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(OFFSET(B2,0,0,COUNTA(B:B)-1)))
=IF(D2<>"", FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=D2), "")
```

But if I am automating it with a script, I can get it as far as transposing it on my Excel spreadsheet, but can't figure out how to then populate column A information underneath.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

// Extract unique values from Column B (excluding header)
  const uniqueValuesRange = worksheet.getRange("B2:B" + worksheet.getUsedRange().getRowCount());
  const uniqueValues: string[][] = uniqueValuesRange.getValues();
  const uniqueRetentionCategories: string[] = uniqueValues.reduce((acc, row) => acc.concat(row), []).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

  // Transpose unique values starting from cell D2 going horizontally
  const transposed2DArray: string[][] = [uniqueRetentionCategories]; // Create 2D array
  const startRange = worksheet.getRange("D2");
  for (let i = 0; i < transposed2DArray.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < transposed2DArray[i].length; j++) {
          const cell = startRange.getCell(i, j);
          cell.setValue(transposed2DArray[i][j]);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): void {
  // Define the source and target ranges
  let targetRange: string = "D2";
  let sheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getUsedRange().getRowCount();
  // Get the data from the source range
  let sourceData: [][] = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + lastRow).getTexts();
  // Organize the data into a new structure
  let newData: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceData.length; i++) {
    let event: string = sourceData[i][0];
    let category: string = sourceData[i][1];
    if (!newData[category]) {
      newData[category] = [];
    }
    newData[category].push(event);
  }
  // console.log(newData)
  // // Write the transformed data to the target range
  let startCell = sheet.getRange(targetRange);
  startCell.getAbsoluteResizedRange(1, Object.keys(newData).length).getEntireColumn().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
  let row = 0;
  for (let category in newData) {
    let values = [category].concat(newData[category]);
    let dataArray: [][] = values.map(value => [value]);
    startCell.getOffsetRange(0, row).getAbsoluteResizedRange(values.length, 1).setValues(dataArray);
    row++;
  }
  console.log("Data transformation complete!");
}
```

---

- Another option to write output to sheet

```js
  // Write the transformed data to the target range
  let startCell = sheet.getRange(targetRange);
  startCell.getAbsoluteResizedRange(1, Object.keys(newData).length).getEntireColumn().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
  let outputData:string[] = [];
  let categories:string[] = Object.keys(newData);
  outputData.push(categories)
  let maxRowCount = Math.max(...categories.map(category => newData[category].length));
  for (let row = 0; row < maxRowCount; row++) {
    let values = categories.map(category => newData[category][row] || "");
    outputData.push(values)
  }
  startCell.getAbsoluteResizedRange(outputData.length, outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
  console.log("Data transformation complete!");
```

[image]